# how to ensure svn branches are pushed to gitlab origin

Tags: git, git-svn, gitlab

Our main repo is stored in svn and I'm using git-svn to create a local git clone of it. I've created a gitlab repo that I want to push to, for use as a mirror or a starting point for others to clone from.

I have 900+ branches in the svn repo and they all show-up in my git clone if I do `git branch -av`. When I push to the gitlab repo, however, none of the branches are shown there. Is there some way to get all of my svn branches to show-up at the origin without explicitly checking out/tracking each of the branches in my local svn clone? At this point, I'm not sure if it's an issue of changing the way I push or of changing the way I init/clone from svn.

Answer (score 0):

Use the scripts provided by atlassian:

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-convert

to convert remote SVN branches to local git branches before pushing local git to gitlab origin:

> java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar ~/svn-migration-scripts.jar clean-git 
>   --force

I would suggest following step by step tutorial for svn to git migration:

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-overview

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've correctly migrated from Subversion to your local repository because you can see all of the branches locally. From there, you just have to figure out how to push the branches to the remote (gitlab) repository. The default behavior of `push` does not do that. From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

> When neither the command-line nor the configuration specify what to
>   push, the default behavior is used, ... the current branch is pushed
>   to the corresponding upstream branch...

You can use the `--all` flag to specify that all branches should be pushed.